# Is it bad practice, or likely to suffer performance issues, to store circular dependencies in objects?

Tags: php, cyclic-reference

Is it bad practice or have a significant performance impact to have a cyclical reference? e.g., add object A as property of object B and then Object B as property of Object A?

An example:

```
<?php 

class Object_A {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new Object_B( $this );       
    }

    public function get_b() {
        return $this->b;
    }

}

class Object_B {

    public function __construct( Object_A $a ) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

[This answer seems to be similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395961/object-a-has-a-reference-to-object-b-which-has-object-a-as-public-property-bad), but for C#.

Comment: It isn't always possible to avoid it, but causes enough problems that you should try to avoid it if at all possible

Comment: This is certainly a design smell. I cannot think of an example where this would be necessary, but it seems that you have. Are you just curious? If this is real work, ask your colleagues. I would try to avoid this if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

For a more general discussion about cyclic references see [What's wrong with circular references?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) on the programmers stackexchange site. But keep in mind the question explicitly states

> I am not asking about homogenous circular references, like those in a doubly-linked list or pointer-to-parent.

PHP implements a garbage collector fully capable of collecting cycles since version 5.3.

Performance considerations are discussed under [Garbage Collection - Performance Considerations](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php) in the manual.